# Records inserted into DynamoDb via typedORM have incorrect Entity info

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-dynamodb, typeorm

When I insert records into my local dynamoDb table via typeDORM in a lambda, it inserts the record with the wrong entity information. For example the GSI1PK

```
GSI1: {
        partitionKey: 'PRO#{{primary_key}}',
        sortKey: 'PRO#{{primary_key}}#YEAR#{{year}}',
        type: INDEX_TYPE.GSI,
    },
```

of a Pro record should be (and is when run the code as an individual node file) PRO#PROCUREMENT_2022 but when I run the same code as a lambda it saves the GSI1PK as an IdList entity LIST#PROLIST_2022. I was able to find out that depending on which Entity I added last in my typedORM.createConnection function, that was the where the GSI1PK information would be built. Is there a reason that the createConnection function is giving different results when the code is run from a lambda vs as a standalone node file?

```
createConnection({
        entities    : [Procurement, IdList],
        name        : 'default',
        table       : testTable,
    }) ;
```

This code works when it is run as a standalone node file and is able to handle the Procurement and IdList entities at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

@Greesemonkey3

Hi, This is the creator of TypeDORM.
There should not be any difference in the behavior when running it inside of a stand-alone node server or in lambda.The entity inserted should always be the same regardless of runtime chosen.

Can you please raise this as an issue in the official [github repository](https://github.com/typedorm/typedorm/issues/new), so that it can be tracked better?